# Don't allow submit form when fields in blank Django Python

Tags: python, django, forms, field

i would like to know how to prevent an user of submitting a form when any of the fields are left in blank, (i know how to validate this on the server side, but i'm looking for an answer on the client side i think)
Thank you!

**

### Update

**
This is my form, it combines some fields from a class that i created (Prestamista) and it also adds 3 fields for the User class, i managed to get the require attribute in the last 3 by adding it to the widget, but i don't know how to set the require argument to the others from the Prestamista Class

```
class MyRegistrationForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model= Prestamista
        fields = ['trabaja', 'sueldo', 'edad']
        fields_required = ['trabaja', 'sueldo', 'edad']
    username = forms.CharField(max_length= 30, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'required': 'true'}))
    password = forms.CharField(required=True, widget = forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'required': 'true'})) 
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': "emailFields",'required': 'true'}))
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also to me this sorta sounds like its not django related, if you want it to happen client side. You might have to get some sort of javascript involved.

Comment: Then you should have tagged this question with Javascript, as that is the only way to enforce anything on the client side.

Comment: @DanielRoseman it should be enough to use `required` with the input to prevent the form from being submitted without using js.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As patrick.ryan93 pointed out you can use `required` with the inputs, but instead of rendering your forms like that you can add it to the widget for the form object.

```
somefield = forms.TextField(
    required=True,
    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'required': 'true'}),
)
```

should render

```
<input type="text" name=... required>
```

which won't be submitted unless all fields have a value: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tLq4jLx8/)

Answer (score 3):

Pass a form to your template, loop through it and set each field to required. No Javascript necessary.

```
{% for field in form %}
    <input type="text"
      class="form-control" 
      name="{{ field.label }}" 
      id="{{ field.name }}"
      value="{{ field.name }}" 
     required />
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Not sure why you got all those downvotes. The OP had never specified if they were using django forms or not at the time of you answering the question. Dont worry. Keep going.. The community needs you answering more questions and helping people.